# Doxygen: Adding a custom link under the "Related Pages" section

Tags: doxygen

I have a several html pages explaining different parts of my code, and I've recently ran Doxygen on it as well. I would like to add links to my current html pages under the Doxygen'd "Related Pages" page.

Is there a way to do this other than manually inserting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Doxygen `\page` command [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdpage).

Comment: This is not a really correct answer, since these files are special doxygen  files, not pre-written HTML files.

Comment: In addition, it's just a link somewhere else.  See [Are answers that just link somewhere else really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: The link is dead.