# Include *prewritten* documentation in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

To distinguish this question from [Doxygen: Adding a custom link under the "Related Pages" section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337307/doxygen-adding-a-custom-link-under-the-related-pages-section) which has an accepted answer that is not a real answer to the question, I specifically add *prewritten* to the question.

What I want:

- Write one document tex file (without preamble, since this file will be `\input`-ed into a full document)
- Import the document into Doxygen's HTML output.

Using Doxygen to produce tex file will probably not work, since it does too much layout work [This holds for its HTML output too like empty table rows 2015]. If Doxygen takes some other input that can easily be transformed into LaTeX, that will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add an already existing Latex file to your doxygen documentation using `\latexonly\input{yourfile}\endlatexonly`.

I would assume you put it e.g. under a doxygen `\page`.

Comment: I can't imagine how doxygen could convert from Latex to HTML. What about writing your documentation in Markdown and include this extra file in the documentation. Markdown is converted to HTML and Latex.

Comment: Using Doxygen to produce tex file will probably not work, since it does too much layout work

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. Who else should convert your existing Latex file to HTML?